# How to colour reference brackets in Latex? All methods I tried, are incompatible with biblatex so I get reference outputted as [?]

Tags: latex, biblatex

To make reference list, I am using biblatex package:

```
\usepackage[ natbib=true, style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{name.bib}
```

I found a way to colour the reference brackets:

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand{\citeleft}{\textcolor{red}{[}}
\renewcommand{\citeright}{\textcolor{red}{]}}
```

I do get the brackets coloured, but the reference shows as [?]. I read that cite package is incompatible with biblatex, but I cannot find how to do it using biblatex. How do I do it?

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `biblatex-ext` package has the handy `\DeclareOuterCiteDelims` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[natbib=true,style=ext-numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{color}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{cite}{\textcolor{green}{\bibopenbracket}}{\textcolor{red}{\bibclosebracket}}

\begin{document}

\cite{knuth:ct}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work as intended. I get the coloured brackets, but inside them are not numbers but the name of the citation I put on .bib file. Why?

Comment: either because you did not run biber or because you are ignoring error messages - as I asked you before, we need a [mre] from you

Comment: I also get the colored brackets, but inside them are not numbers but the name of the citation. I can't seem to color the number and the brackets.